# Spring boot build variants Profile-specific properties with gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have different configs `application-prod.properties` and `application-beta.properties` files
I run it by: `-Dspring.profiles.active=beta` or `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`

It works but also I use gradle:

```
war {
    baseName = 'beta'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I want to use variable from application.properties and set to baseName. How to pass variable from application.properties to baseName in gradle file?

on code level I do it like this:

```
@Value("${baseName}")
private String baseName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read in the properties file and use it, a Gradle script is Groovy so you can use any Groovy code like:

```
Properties applicationProperties = new Properties()
file('application.properties').withInputStream {
    applicationProperties.load(it)
}
war {
    baseName = applicationProperties.baseName
}
```